# Scripts not loading in browser with error Uncaught ReferenceError:autosize not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open a page via the nav menu in my CRUD app,and I have to keep on refreshing the page manually to load the scripts included in the HTML view with the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page. These scripts are linked via CDNs and some of them are stored in the app's directory. The problem is that if I load the page in a new window, the JS loads fine. If I load it in the same window, it gives the following errors:

```
forms-elements.js:87 
Uncaught ReferenceError: autosize is not definedpageLoad @ forms-elements.js:87
(anonymous function) @ forms-elements.js:125
j @ jquery.min.js:2
add @ jquery.min.js:2
n.fn.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
n.fn.init @ jquery.min.js:2
n @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @ forms-elements.js:1
app.js:268 scripts loaded.
```

The following code is at `forms-elements.js:87`:

```
autosize($('.autogrow'));
```

Then there is another error right below it:

```
VM874 create:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: enableFormNewUser is not defined
onclick @ VM874 create:1
```

The following code exists at `VM874 create:1`:

```
(function(event){enableFormNewUser();})
```

Could someone tell what is VM874 in this case? And why is this error appearing and stopping the JS from loading unless a new window is opened or the page is refreshed. The caching is DISABLED in the browsers.

Comment: Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Don't know the code, but do you do anything different on page update, than you do on page load? Check for something else, run different scripting, show other items on the page than on first load, and so on?